# server unexpectedly closed network connection in raspberry pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I am new to Raspberry Pi. I have a Pi 2 kit model B.I am using an angry IP address and I can find Raspberry Pi's address using it. When I configure it using `sudo raspi-config`, make necessary changes and then say OK to reboot, I get this error in putty:

> `Server unexpectedly closed network connection.`

[image]

How do I correct this issue?

Further, I have connected Raspberry Pi 2 with an Ethernet cable to the laptop. I have completed necessary steps like changing adapter settings, edited properties of Wi-Fi to allow other network users to connect to computers Internet connection but still I have no Internet access shown for unidentified Internet connection.[image]

How can I solve this? Please suggest the necessary steps to be implemented

Answer (score 0):

For me too many process and session running for a particular user is the cause of your problem so alternatively I logged in as root and ran the following commands:

```
ps -fp $(pgrep -d, -u adminuser)

pkill -9 -u adminuser
```

After this I can login normally in putty like ever before.